# Unable to position uiimageview using CGPoint saved from NSUserDefaults and inputting the CGpoint to CGRectMake

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a bunch of draggable images using UIImageView and I want the position of the images to be saved. I have tried using NSUserDefaults to save the CGPoint of a touched image and then load it's position by CGRectMake when that view controller is opened. When I run and open that view controller there is error.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
//create location as CGPoint 

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(location) forKey:@"key"];
//get location as NSString

[defaults synchronize];
//saves
}
```

The last location of an image in CGPoint is converted into NSString and saved.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
CGPoint position = CGPointFromString([defaults objectForKey:@"s1X"]);
//set position as CGpoint 

profile[1].frame = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, 25, 35);
//assign image using the coordinates saved.
}
```

When the View controller is opened the position should be loaded, but the simulator stops when I open the Viewcontroller. Please help me solve this error.

EDIT: I used NSMutableArray to store the CGPoint, when I run the code and open that page simulator terminates again(Thread 1:signal SIGABRT). And I can't find a way to assign the index for the array.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches] anyObject];
UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=1; i<12; i++) {
    if(profile[i].isExclusiveTouch) {
        [dataArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)] objectAtIndex:i];
        // how to store the CGPoint at i index?
    }
  }
[defaults setObject:dataArray forKey:@"key"];
[defaults synchronize];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *dataArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
//Only showed 3 images for example
CGPoint point1 = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:1] CGPointValue];
CGPoint point2 = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:2] CGPointValue];
CGPoint point3 = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:3] CGPointValue];
profile[1].frame = CGRectMake(point1.x-11, point1.y-15, 22, 30);
profile[2].frame = CGRectMake(point2.x-11, point2.y-15, 22, 30);
profile[3].frame = CGRectMake(point3.x-11, point3.y-15, 22, 30);
}
```

**Another question**
How do I assign the CGPoint to index i?

```
valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)]];
//Can't use objectAtIndex or atIndex to assign, there will be error.
```

Comment: Typo? `key` vs. `s1X`?

Comment: Oh I see, didn't know the ForKey matters. Now just need to figure out a way to save positions of multiple image.

Comment: Use multiple different keys or an array of points.

Comment: Using `NSUserDefaults` to communicate between different view controllers is not what it was designed for.

Comment: But this is all in the same view controllers. What I'm trying to do is to save the position of any image moved so that when the user leave the view controller, the image will be at the latest position and not the original position.

Comment: @Bronx OK, that is fair enough.  So now why do you start at index `1` (`[dataArray objectAtIndex:1]`)?

Comment: @Droppy that is to get the coordinates in the dataArray, so index 1 is the latest position for profile[1] the imageview and so on. Seem like the index is causing the error.

Comment: There is error an (no visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray') at line ` [dataArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)] objectAtIndex:i];` when I add `objectAtIndex:i`. How do I add in the index?